# GUID vs random string as identifier

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I have a table where I want to have a unique identifier that is the same across database instances which I can reference in my code. The table is very unlikely to have > 500 rows. Is there a difference between using a GUID and using an NVARCHAR(6) populated by LEFT(NEWID(),6) as the identifier; assuming of course that the field is marked as a PK and is unique.

The ID is going to be used in a custom control and I think that:

```
<cc1:mycontrol id="test" runat="server" code="71E29D" />
```

Is more readable than and easier to use than:

```
<cc1:mycontrol id="test" runat="server" code="71E29D4C-A00A-4F1A-9785-08D030A9B764" />
```

Comment: random != unique

Comment: Use GUID, they are meant for this purposes, and for scalability of your software too.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use an int?

Comment: @DerekTomes  as he says, he wants uniqueness across databases, which is what GUIDs are good for, meaning you can create rows on different machines, stored in different databases, and can merge it all together and there will be no PK conflicts

Comment: A sequence can provide the uniqueness across databases too.

Comment: @steoleary  if you use some kind of block allocation scheme, but that requires a bit more planning

Comment: I need the Id's to be unique and match on both my dev machine and the production one so that when I reference them in my code and then deploy they match up. I suppose I could use an Int but I would need to insert it instead of using an auto increment. Seems like I should just go with the guid based on the comments and answers so far.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, he says he wants "...a unique identifier that is the same across database instances..." I'm assuming that means the same id is required in each database, not a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By truncating the GUID, you may end up with duplicates.  Just use the GUID.   ( or come up with another scheme for shorter unique IDs)

Comment: Ok. I guess I'll just go with the guid and have my code be a little more difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware of different GUID generation schemes. In some cases, a lot of the bytes are not random, but based of MAC addresses and other such system stuff. That could mean that your first 6 characters will always be the same...

Answer (score 2):

GUIDs aren't supposed to be readable really. They are used to ensure uniqueness of IDs. If you use only a portion of a GUID, officially it cannot be guaranteed to be unique. Consider having a pair, I've had a GUID as the my rowId and then a second column to be some readable value.